# .net framework 2.0 C# and json webquery format string

Tags: c#, json, web-services, formatting, httpwebrequest

I have created a webservice in C# which looks like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string UpdateHeatCallJSON(string json)
    {
        HeatItem item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HeatItem>(json);
        UpdateHeatCall(item);
        HeatItemResponse response = new HeatItemResponse();
        //... more code
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    }
```

I basically have an object HeatItem, which I want to pass in as an argument.

I currently consume the web service (for testing) in a C# console application and having challenges finding the correct format. This is my call:

```
   static void UpdateHeatItemJSON()
    {
        // corrected to WebRequest from HttpWebRequest
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestServer + "/UpdateHeatCallJSON");

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        string postData = "";
        postData = @"{'json':'{""BusinessPartner"":""00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"",""CaseNumber"":4,""CaseDescription"":""first case"",""CaseType"":"""",""CaseSeverity"":"""",""DueDate"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""AssignmentNumber"":5,""AssignmentDescription"":"""",""AssignmentCreation"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""AssignmentTime"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""ChangeDate"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""ChangeTime"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""Group"":"""",""SubGroup"":"""",""Module"":"""",""AssignmentStatus"":"""",""KPIChallenge"":false,""KPI1Status"":"""",""KPI1User"":"""",""KPI1Date"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""KPI1Time"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""KPI2Status"":"""",""KPI2User"":"""",""KPI2Date"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""KPI2Time"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00"",""SessionID"":null}'}";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(postData);

        //get a reference to the request-stream, and write the postData to it
        using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                sw.Write(postData);
        }

        //get response-stream, and use a streamReader to read the content
        using (Stream s = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                string jsonData = sr.ReadToEnd();
                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
                JToken jHeatItem = jObject["HeatItem"];
            }
        }
    }
```

Looking at postData above, formatting the json string as above works, however when I validate the string at http://jsonlint.com/ the validation fails. When I pass in a validated json string like this:

{
    "json": {
        "BusinessPartner": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "CaseNumber": 4,
        "CaseDescription": "first case",
        "CaseType": "",
        "CaseSeverity": "",
        "DueDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "AssignmentNumber": 5,
        "AssignmentDescription": "",
        "AssignmentCreation": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "AssignmentTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ChangeDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ChangeTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "Group": "",
        "SubGroup": "",
        "Module": "",
        "AssignmentStatus": "",
        "KPIChallenge": false,
        "KPI1Status": "",
        "KPI1User": "",
        "KPI1Date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "KPI1Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "KPI2Status": "",
        "KPI2User": "",
        "KPI2Date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "KPI2Time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "SessionID": null
    }
}

the webservice returns a 500 Internal Server Error, which I believe is because it does not like the argument passed in. I am relatively new to this and I am wondering if anyone can help me understand this a bit better.

Also looking at the response (for the working example), the return json contains three backslaches \\ I believe to escape the quotation marks. This makes this call

```
                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
                JToken jHeatItem = jObject["HeatItem"];
```

to fail. Any ideas why?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Json strings need to use double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling like an idiot wasting a lot of time on this, now as everyhing is so easy. Let asp.net take care of it. Followed the steps in this post and all is working perfectly

http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the request, I added `request.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";`. Make sure the Service is decorated with the `ScriptService` attribute. E.g.,

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]    
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

When you are formatting your post data, this style worked for me:

`@"{""json"":'{""test"": ""value""}'}";`

The key thing seemed to be ensuring there was a single quote surrounding the JSON after the initial colon.

In terms of the unwanted backslash characters, check out this link http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/. Essentially the deal is that you return an object from your service, rather than a string. The same would thing would apply to passing objects into your service.

Comment: Yes that is the formatting that works for me as well, still trying to understand why I can't use a string that is can get validated. And the one that works can't be validated (at some of the json string validation sites)
Anyway I should be happy getting it to work. Still struggling with the backslashes though.

Comment: Why not try returning a `HeatItemResponse` from the service rather than a string? If the JSON serialization works like it should you shouldn't get the backslashes.